# keras: how to add weights to loss evaluation

Tags: keras

**Todo :**

- I would like to add a weight for each pattern loss in a given Keras loss function.

  > **For example:** 
  > if the error on pattern i is l_i, 
  > I would like to consider, instead, an error l_i * c_i, where c_i is an input scalar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def customloss(y_true, y_pred):
    c_i = ...
    loss = ...(only use tensor operations on y_true and y_pred or use built in keras losses)
    return c_i*loss
```

Now compile your model passing the loss function.

```
model.compile(loss = customloss)
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance: are y_true and y_pred tensors (arrays in this case) covering all patterns? In other words, loss is the loss on a single pattern or the overall loss?

Comment: yes y_true and y_pred are tensors, when training your keras model will call this loss function to calculate the loss. Your loss function needs to return a single value tensor. So it needs to calculate overall loss.

Comment: For my needs, I would consider inserting costs just inside the loss on a single pattern:
loss_i * c_i

Comment: I mean: usually a loss is the sum of a function of y_true and y_pred for every pattern. I need to associate costs to a pattern level.

Comment: lets say your set of single patter losses for a batch are [1,2,3,4] if you multiply all of them by c you'll get [c, 2*c, 3,c, 4c] and the mean of those will be c*[mean([1,2,3,4])], keras' built in loss functions return you the means so all you need to do is multiplying it by c.

If you want to multiply them by different weights you need to implement the loss function from scratch, you may go to https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py  to get a starting point. all you want to do is multiplying the loss tensor with c_i vector before K.mean() call.

Comment: The problem is that every loss in the batch would have a different cost. Therefore I'm writing the loss from scratch.

Comment: Im modifiyng the binary_crossentropy loss: I've this error when i'm trying to execute the code:
 for i in range(0, y_true.shape[0]):
TypeError: 'TensorVariable' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: I mean, I wrote from scratch the binary_crossentropy loss as defined in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303229/why-does-keras-binary-crossentropy-loss-function-return-wrong-values

Comment: Many thanks! I still haven't found a clue, however I appricciate your help.

Comment: However, does anybody know how to print the shape of y_pred inside the loss function? I'm trying to write it to a file but it says that I can't pass a tensor to f.write(). Should I convert it to a string?

Comment: You shouldn't be using for loops with tensors, shape of y_pred would be (None, 1) ,  if you evaluate the tensor and print the shape of the resulting numpy array you would get the shape (batch_size, 1).

Comment: If you are trying to multiply losses of each sample from the batch with a different scaler, put those scalers into a numpy array, use 
tf.convert_to_tensor to cast the numpy array into a tensor, now use matmul on your loss tensor before calculating its mean.

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean with "loss tensor"? Suppose I've c as a numpy array with costs inside, y_true and y_pred, and I want to implement a "scaled" binary_crossentropy loss. What should I do?

Comment: I mean, should the custom loss return a tensor or a scalar number?

Comment: And how do I know to which input samples the y_true and y_pred tensors entries are related to? They are related to a batch (a fragment of the entire training set), I need the corresponding indexes to the training set.

Comment: Ok, the loss returns a tensor, What I miss now is:
1 -  how the final scalar loss is computed (the sum of the loss tensor entries?)
2  - how to correlate batches y_true, y_pred indexes to original samples.
Any help would be very appriciated!

Comment: Since your loss is a function of two tensors it is also a tensor. You may sum your final losses with K.sum() but you should return the mean not the sum. So use K.mean() instead. y_true and y_pred has the same order as the original batch samples. How does your model generate batches? I do not know, but you should. What should you do if your model shuffles the data before sampling? make a custom generator and create the batches yourself this way you can shuffle the scalers the same way. Or disable shuffling.

Comment: if you are going to give each class a different weight you could use y_truth to determine what c value you should use for each row of data. if your data is categorical y_truth will look like [[0,0,1],[0,1,0]] for number of classes of 3 and batch size of 2. If you matmul this with a column tensor that contains scalars for each class  you will get the column vector of the scalars you need for this batch.

Comment: I think it would be more reasonable If I could send the code to you. Do you have an email?

Comment: It is based on a keras tutorial, and I'm modifying it in order to add costs inside the custum loss function.